# Change the symbol for a single feature in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, symbology, features

Is it possible to change the symbol for a single feature in ArcObjects? If so how?

I know it's possible to setup the map symbology for different field values of a feature class, but I'd like to achieve this without changing any of the underlying field data if possible.

P.S. I'm using C# and ArcGIS 10.0

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasons for wanting to do this, and whether you are going to use it in ArcMap, ArcEngine, or on ArcGIS Server? Does it need to be done through ArcObjects and not the layer's symbology tab or alternatively can't you just create a selection layer consisting of the one feature? Does the symbology need to show up in the map's table of contents and legend?

Comment: Doing it in ArcObjects; it's a stand-alone C# app. I'd rather not do it in the symbology tab because that would mean changing a property (I think), and I want to avoid that if possible. I'm not familiar with the selection layer approach. No need to show up in TOC or legend.

Comment: In ArcMap you would select a feature, right-click its layer in the TOC and go to Selection-Create layer from selected features. This would create a new layer with just the selected feature(s). You could get the same effect with a layer with a definition query. I am not sure how this would work in ArcEngine as I don't use it. But I think the layers approach is probably simplest.